# SPServices + SharePoint-Hosted Add-in in a development site

Tags: spservices, sharepoint-addin

I've tried to deploy SPServices library into a SP Add-in in a developer site collection, but I'm getting the attached error.

Notes:

- The add-in consumes data from another SiteCollection (a)
- I've tested it consuming the `jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js` both from the
  hostWeb (a) and from the rootWeb of the add-in web. The error persists
- $.support.cors is set to true.

[image: errors]

Is this unexpected? What do you recommend me to try?

tks!

Answer (score 0):

try the cross domain library "SP.RequestExecutor.js", and you don't need to use SPServices now, as the REST API is quite good now.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx

Comment: I've been using SP.RequestExecutor.js for a while. I was trying to implement SPServices to get ListItem versions, but gave up for now, since it's not making cors. tks anyway!

Comment: I haven't try this, if you use `$.ajax({  url: "../_api/SP.WebProxy.invoke", type: "POST",` 
like the sample here: http://blog.ch.atosconsulting.com/data-access-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps/
And include your site collection in the "Remote EndPoints", will this work?

Comment: gonna try this, and feedback you. tks

Comment: What if you really want to use SPServices though?

Comment: You can have a look Marc D Anderson's blog, I'm not sure cross domain is supported.